# Efficient looping in an accept/reject algorithm

Tags: python, performance, random

Below are two different implementations of a basic Accept/Reject sampler from a Gaussian density function known only up to some 'unknown' normalising constant, now the basic sampler (*Method 1*) involves repeatedly looping and generating the two required random variables required at each step within that loop.

For *Method 2* on the otherhand a batch of these random variables are simulated, then looped through for the first acceptance, if there are none then a new batch is simulated and so on. Now when the acceptance probability is small *Method 2* does seem to be substantially faster so my first question is can *Method 2* be more efficiently implemented? And if this pre-simulating batches of random variables is the most efficient method then is there a principled way of choosing how large these batches should be?

#### Setup

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from numpy.random import uniform

q = norm(loc=0., scale=3.)
def p_(x):
    return np.exp(-0.5*x**2)

k = 1./q.pdf(0.)
```

#### AR Method 1

```
def AR1():
    while True:
        z = q.rvs()
        u = uniform(low=0., high=k*q.pdf(z))
        if u <= p_(z):
            return z
```

#### AR Method 2

```
BATCH_SIZE = 5
def AR2():
    nt = 0
    Zs = q.rvs(size=BATCH_SIZE)            # random variables z ~ q(z)
    Us = uniform(low=0., high=k*q.pdf(Zs)) # uniform rvs on [0, k*q(z)]
    Pvals = p_(Zs)                         # unnormalised pdf p_(z)
    while True:
        if Us[nt] <= Pvals[nt]:
            return Zs[nt]
        else:
            nt +=1
            if nt > BATCH_SIZE - 1:
                Zs = q.rvs(size=BATCH_SIZE)            
                Us = uniform(low=0., high=k*q.pdf(Zs)) 
                Pvals = p_(Zs)
                nt = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since samples from AR are independent, you don't need to generate them one by one as metropolis hastings algorithm. Therefore, you can generate them all at once and speed up the function by utilizing the array operation.

Suppose we want 1000 samples. Use your AR2:

```
>> %timeit sample2 = [AR2() for _ in range(1000)]
513 ms ± 134 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

We can instead create a array like function:

```
def AR_array(size = 100):
    # generate a slightly larger total samples 
    # based on the acceptance ratio: 1/k
    Zs = q.rvs(size= np.int(size*(k+1)))   
    Us = uniform(low=0., high=k*q.pdf(Zs))
    Pvals = p_(Zs)                  # unnormalized pdf p_(z)
    Zs_accepted = Zs[Us <= Pvals]   # select accepted samples
    return Zs_accepted[0:size]      # return the required sample size
```

Generate 1000 samples.

```
>> %timeit AR_array(1000)
1.9 ms ± 209 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Sanity check:

```
>> norm.fit(AR_array(1000)) # MLE of mean and std
(-0.05960200510480021, 0.9917248073504155)
```